# Can I put my computer cabinet (tower) on its side, or does it need to stand up?

Tags: case

Sorry for asking a Dumb Question but I am just too Curious to know .

1) Do I always need to put my computer in stand up position or can i put it on its sides.

2) Do I need any kind of special cabinets to put it on its side

3) What are the Pros and Cons of putting it on its side and stand up position

4) Now-a-days why most of the CPU come in a stand up position cabinets

Comment: Watch out for cables that hang into fans when you put your computer on its side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***1 -*** you can put it on it's sides.

***2 -*** no.

***3 -*** Cons: you will have trouble putting CD/DVDs in the drive 'cause they will keep falling out and alike. Also, some may argue that ventilation will be a little worse. In general, those things are generally ment to be in upward position, although in practice they work in all kinds of positions.
Another con is that it will take considerable more space on the floor/table ...

***4 -*** more practical that way. Also, heated air tends to go up, so you also have a sort of a natural ventilation that way.

Comment: Second this.  A CD on it's side is just asking for dropped disks.  This would be a big problem if there is ever a software ejection of a disk--say, after burning one...

Comment: The only problem are 8cm optical disks. They must be placed in a drive in horizontal position because they are designed to just drop into the groove in drive tray. This may be localized phenomena, but all drives I've seen have small catches which will hold 12cm disks when they are ejected from the drive.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - Andreja, you're absolutely right. I forgot all about those, since I never used them, and the laptop I'm working on nowadays doesn't have them, so they're not in my sight every day. However, it has been my feeling that although they're common on normal CD drives, most people don't actually know what they're there for (their purpose).

Comment: If you lay it on its side, it's more stable so the hard disk get less damage by unintentional shaking.